# Como usar variável de classe como valor padrão em funções de php?

Tags: php

```
class Teste(){
  public variavel;
  public variavela;

  function teste($parametro=$this->variavel, $parametro2->$this->variavela){
    // code
  }
}
```

Me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Não faz sentido fazer isso. Uma vez que você pode pegar o valor da variavel da classe a qualquer momento dentro da função não entendo qual a necessidade de passar o valor no parametro...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não pode fazer isso, os valores-padrão de parâmetros precisam ser constantes. O máximo que o PHP permite é usar constantes de classe, com referência estática:

```
class Teste {
  const VARIAVEL = 10;
  const VARIAVELA = 20;

  function __construct($parametro=self::VARIAVEL, $parametro2=self::VARIAVELA){
    echo "$parametro - $parametro2";
  }
}

$t = new Teste();
```

http://ideone.com/l1NX5y

Se bem que nesse caso já vale mais a pena colocar os valores literais diretamente na assinatura da função, não é? Fica mais limpo:

```
class Teste {   
  function __construct($parametro=10, $parametro2=20){
    echo "$parametro - $parametro2";
  }
}

$t = new Teste();
```

Se você precisa de uma solução com valores dinâmicos, atribua os valores dentro da própria função, como o @AndréRibeiro sugeriu na [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50069).

Comment: Obrigado por enviar a fonte da resposta, me ajuda com minhas pesquisas futuras. Isso resolve meu problema.

Comment: Ok, mas eu acho que a resposta do André Ribeiro é o caminho mais recomendado. Isso que eu postei está mais pra gambiarra...

Answer (score 10):

O que você está tentando fazer não é válido no PHP.

Segundo o [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#example-123):

> O valor padrão [de um parâmetro de função] precisa ser uma expressão constante, não (por exemplo)
>   uma variável, um membro de classe ou uma chamada de função.

Uma alternativa com um funcionamento similar:

```
class Teste(){
  public $variavel;
  public $variavela;

  function teste($parametro = null, $parametro2 = null){
    $parametro = $parametro ? $parametro : $this->variavel;
    $parametro2 = $parametro2 ? $parametro2 : $this->variavela
  }
}
```

Nesse exemplo, caso algum dos parâmetros não seja passado na chamada da função, o valor padrão será o valor do membro da classe.

Comment: Sua resposta também me ajudou, porem devo assumir que a forma como bfavaretto apresentou é mais 'dry'. Obrigado.

Comment: @LucasAnjos a resposta o bfavaretto resolve o problema mas ela não tem nada de mais DRY que esta. Esta é 100% [DRY](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).